# How to call a button function in javascript from firefox console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code for the button calls my js function. How can I call the function directly in the firefox developer console without pressing the button?

```
<div id="menuFifthButton" name="menuFifthButton" class="menuFifthButton">
    <a href="javascript:rootFrame.showTrainStations();" border="0">
        //code
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure of what is really your question but in short type : rootFrame.showTrainStations() and it should do the work.

Comment: You have to learn the basics of javascript with html a little bit

Comment: I already tried but this gave me an `ReferenceError: rootFrame is not defined` error

Comment: Isn't it better to use `onclick=" "`?

Answer (score 0):

Give `id` selector to your `a` tag. you have to change like this 
  `<a type="button" onclick="javascript:rootFrame.showTrainStations();" id="linkButton">`

Then type `$('#linkButton').click()` in console

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke your JavaScript function from the console tool in Firefox. You will be responsible to provide it with any argument if your function takes any.

[image: This image shows how to open console tool in Firefox]

You can also use: Ctrl+Shift+K

Answer (score 0):

Try dispatching a click event with javascript.

```
var element = document.getElementById('menuFifthButton');
var event = new Event('click');
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

EDIT: but you might have to target the 'a' tag, so try also with that.

```
var element = document.getElementById('menuFifthButton').getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
var event = new Event('click');
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

EDIT2: Looking at it more carefully, i'm not sure a click will do anything. By looking at just the code you supplied a hyphotetical click would trigger a function .showTrainStations on rootFrame variable, but there is no setting of the variable, or the actuall function .showTrainStations. I'm affraid "ReferenceError: rootFrame is not defined" will be the result of every click. Is there a chance you provide more code and the actuall result you are trying to achieve?